# iOS 8.3 pushViewController shows empty view first, then view is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

iOS 8.3 changed the behavior of pushViewController to show blank view first, then the view is shown. Any tips to fix this issue?

Same code on different iOS versions

- iOS 8.3 broken behavior: https://vid.me/4JDf
- iOS 8.2 expected behavior: https://vid.me/qgvA

The basic code that pushes the view:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

PS: The VC's code is under NDA, sadly I can not share it.

Comment: If you can't share the exact code, create a small sample project that shows the same problem, and post the relevant parts here.

Comment: …and you'll often find that in isolating the problem, the solution becomes apparent.

Comment: Thanks Ashley, that's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Please set background color for view.view any color except clear color

Comment: It's already set to black. I set it to pink to test this. It just comes in pink and still has the same behavior.

Comment: Can you please post code of view controller some where?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I would post it directly in the question if it wasn't under NDA.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a layout clash issue in the new view. Commenting out some layout based code solved the issue. Basically we had more layoutIfNeeded than needed.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```